# Does Server to Server REST Communication Need SSL?

Tags: php, apache-2.4

## Background

I have two separate servers. `Server 1` is my primary server, which the client will connect to directly, and which hosts most of my content.

`Server 2` contains specific data which isn't available on `Server 1`. `Server 2` is a completely separate instance, and separate URL entirely.

`Server 1` has `PHP` installed, and I use `file_get_contents()` to retrieve information from `Server 2` (similar to how Google recommends pinging it's servers for reCaptcha). In the screenshot (below), the `?` is the server to server connection that I am concerned about. Right now, it's using `https` as the connection, but I want to know if that is necessary.

[image]

## Questions

First off, do I need to use SSL for the connection between `Server 1` and `Server 2`?

Second, should I be using HTTP at all for this connection, regardless of whether it's protected by SSL? I've heard the term CURL, would that be a replacement?

Answer (score 3):

First: It's probably best to err on the side of extra security these days. If you implement TLS (what SSL has become) between the two servers, it will make intercepting the traffic much more difficult. If you use trusted certificates, man in the middle attacks become much harder to perform.

Next: If you then implement TLS between the servers and notice severe performance issues, it may be time to re-evaluate the usage. Does the transmission NEED to be secure? Can options be tuned such as connection pooling or session caching?

Finally: CURL is an application generally operating over http/https not a protocol in and of itself. You can use curl to make http/s requests, but i am unaware of a curl:// style protocol.

And to re-iterate: In the modern hyper security context of the web where people will find and break any hole left in your implementation if there is value, it always best to attempt to implement as much security as possible. If you are transferring sensitive data between servers, you generally wind up liable when something goes awry.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure no-one can intercept the traffic between your servers 1 and 2, you need to use TLS.

If you accept that the traffic can be intercepted or altered between servers 1 and 2, then you can use HTTP.

Comment: Please say TLS and not SSL. Also, just using TLS is not enough. If you want to be resistant to spoofing, you need to verify the host certificates exchanged at the beginning of the TLS handshake. Otherwis you may be communicating with the wrong endpoint. I believe this is needed to be put forward more often because it is too frequent to see insecure ways of using TLS, with a program just allowing any self signed certificate...

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, it is a bad habit from me, because SSL is the more widely understood term for secure connections.